# How to Group associative array elements on similar keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array

```
$array = [ 
    { "key": "2.1", "value": "11", "quantity": "1" }, 
    { "key": "2.1", "value": "22", "quantity": "1" }, 
    { "key": "2.5", "value": "19", "quantity": "1" } 
]
```

Now I want to group it by similar keys.

The output should be:

```
$array = [ 
    { "key": "2.1", "value": "11, 22", "quantity": "2" }, 
    { "key": "2.5", "value": "19", "quantity": "1" } 
]
```

I have tried like this but it is not working:

```
    $remove_key = [];

    for($len=0; $len<count($array); $len++) {
       if( isset($array[$len+1]) AND
             $array[$len]['key'] == $array[$len+1]['key']
         ) {
             $array[$len]['value'] = $array[$len]['value'] .', '. $array[$len+1]['value'];
             $array[$len]['quantity'] = $array[$len]['quantity'] + $array[$len+1]['quantity'];

              array_push($remove_key, $len+1);
         }

    }

    for($rem=0; $rem<count($remove_key); $rem++) {
        unset($array[$remove_key[$rem]]);
    }

    $array = array_values(($array));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `foreach()` and `json_encode()` will do the job for you:

```
<?php

$json = '[ 
    { "key": "2.1", "value": "11", "quantity": "1" }, 
    { "key": "2.1", "value": "22", "quantity": "1" }, 
    { "key": "2.5", "value": "19", "quantity": "1" } 
]';

$array = json_decode($json,true);

$final = [];

foreach($array as $arr){
    
    $final[$arr['key']]['key'] = $arr['key'];
    $final[$arr['key']]['value'] = (isset($final[$arr['key']]['value'])) ? $final[$arr['key']]['value'].','. $arr['value'] : $arr['value'];
    $final[$arr['key']]['quantity'] = (isset($final[$arr['key']]['quantity'])) ?  $final[$arr['key']]['quantity']+ $arr['quantity'] : $arr['quantity'];
}

echo $json = json_encode(array_values($final));
```

Output : https://3v4l.org/H6grg